# Given the probability of an event, find the sample size necessary?

Tags: statistics

A bunch of people in a room each pick their own random number between 1 and 100. If you run 1000 trials:

How many people must there be in order to make it more than 50% likely that at least 3 people pick the same number?

Here is what I know:
1-P(only 2 the same)-P(only 1 the same) > .5
I don't know how to solve from here though...

Supposedly you can solve this very easily on excel, however I cannot get it to work to save my life. I really need help, because I have been working on this problem for over 4 hours now.

Comment: You could start with finding the probability that if there are $n$ people, then $m$ numbers are chosen by two people each and $n-2m$ numbers are chosen by one person each.  Then add these up over $m$ with $0 \le m \le \frac{n}{2}$ and subtract from  $1$.

Comment: This is an entry level statistics class so i have no idea how to do that.... We are supposed to use excel for this, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.